# Create a random disposable mail receiver

Tags: php, email, web, spam, mail-server

I need to create random e-mail addresses that possess the role of receivers. Though these addresses should not be in any case real e-mails. I know that this kind of problem could easily be solved by creating something like `Random_root@dummy_host.com` . But the real deal is that there's a case my CMS will notify via e-mail these accounts, and so in this case the server will have a re-bounce mail traffic or even worse the host could be black-listed as spam.

I am thinking a mail server that dispose any kind of non existed mail address at its host but I can't find any applicable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Though not a PHP solution there is a web based service that runs off an API you can use, take a look at http://mailgun.net/

Comment: Well, I don't need a tracking system Just a host that will dispose any e-mail that I'll send. e.g radnom_root@anyhost.com

so anyhost.com should dispose any mail from any random e-mail address.

Answer (score 0):

Again not a direct PHP solution but http://cloudmailin.com will allow you to send to any email address at your domain, you can then use a 403 status in your app to reject email to anything you're not expecting and the mail server will actually refuse the message.

Comment: That looks interesting, but yet e-mails are randomly created. I need to sign them up first to implement this solution. So I don't think this'll work :/

Comment: If you use the custom domain feature you can then accept anything that comes to your domain? I think that might be what you're looking for?